Open Telemetry spans are not properly gettings their parent's span ID. (invalid parent span IDs=; skipping clock skew adjustment)
I am trying to add tracing to my microservice application, which is built using ASP.NET. In general, when looking around, everybody recommends doing something like this. Because my application uses a WebHost instead of a WebApplication, I added the Open telemetry elements in the Startup.cs file, like this:
public virtual IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // configure Open Telemetry
    services.AddOpenTelemetry()
        .ConfigureResource(resource => resource
            .AddService(
                serviceName: $"{Configuration["SubscriptionClientName"]} Service",
                serviceVersion: "1.0.0"))
        .WithTracing(builder => builder
            .SetSampler(new AlwaysOnSampler())
            .AddSource(names: $"{Configuration["SubscriptionClientName"]} Service")
            .SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService(serviceName: $"{Configuration["SubscriptionClientName"]} Service"))
            .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
            .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
            .AddGrpcClientInstrumentation()
            .AddEntityFrameworkCoreInstrumentation()
            .AddOtlpExporter(options =>
            {
                options.Endpoint = new Uri("http://jaeger-allinone-collector.jaeger-observability.svc.cluster.local:4317");
                options.Protocol = OtlpExportProtocol.Grpc;
            }));
...

In Program.cs, the relevant code is this
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
     WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .OtherStuff()
        .Build();

When I run this, I can see that Jaeger is receiving the spans. However, the called service, Customer, when called from another service, Telemetry, is presented in the same trace but not as a child call of Telemetry. As seen bellow

Additionally, I can see this warning in the Customer service
.
To my understanding, the issue is that the Telemetry service is not properly sending its span ID to the Customer service. Using .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation() and .AddHttpClientInstrumentation() should be enough for this to take place, I thought, but clearly not working. I suspect it is a configuration issue but I don't know what else to try out.
In the end, what I want is for the Customer service to appear as a child of the Telemetry service.

What this is implying is like more that there is a missing span somewhere, that the call from telemetry to customer is going through a system that is adding a span that you don't see. That happens with certain vendored agents when they're running on the machine, and systems like Azure Functions. How are these running? Have you tried running them locally in isolation?

@MartinDotNet Did not know the system could modify the span. These services are running on AKS, as separate pods. I have not tried running them locally because we don't have such a setup.

So I was able to finally find the issue. I was debating if I should delete my question but maybe somebody else has a similar issue in the future.
So my services (Telemetry and Customer) are running in a Kubernetes cluster. The issue was that Telemetry's "GET" request was going through another resource. So the request that the Customer received had the Parent Spand ID from that in-between service. I reconfigured the communication to happen directly between the services and now I get the results I expected.
In the end, it was a networking miss-configuration, not an Open Telemetry miss-configuration.
